# Why does the Numpy community provide 32bit binaries installer but not 64bit?

Tags: python, numpy, binaries

The Numpy community provides 32bit binaries installer [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.1/)

[image]

but no 64bit binaries installer.

---

If they were **no binaries installer at all**, it would be coherent, and I would understand it as a deliberate choice meaning *"You should compile and build it yourself."*
But this is not true, as 32bit binaries installers are provided.

**Is there a technical reason why 64bit binaries installers for Numpy are not officially available?**

*PS: I know http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but here is only Numpy-MKL, and I'm not sure if this works on every machine because of Intel MKL.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) creator :

> There is no decent open-source (free) Fortran compiler for the Windows 64bit platform. As a consequence, it's **impossible** to build **NumPy** on this platform using only free and open-source tools. That's why there is no official Windows 64bit binaries for this library .

The only ready-to-use installers available out there are the ones you have mentioned ,they use Intel Fortran compiler and these are clearly unofficial binaries.

refer to [discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2013-February/065339.html) regarding this matter .

**Edit**: If you are concerned about performance of the **MKL** version , both testing and real world experience show that Intel compilers and **MKL** usually provide the best performance even on **AMD** systems.

Comment: Thanks. The version here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy is a "MKL" version. I don't know what it is. Will it 100% work on all computers? Or only on Intel processors? Does using a MKL version imply a restriction?

Comment: Something else: I used Anaconda (x64 version) before (if I remember well) and it was shipped with Numpy. What Numpy build does Anaconda use ?

Comment: @Basj Not sure what MKL is but I've used that for years without problems. Haven't found any restrictions.

Comment: Ok @Alexander, I knew what the name stands for ;) When I say I don't know what it is, I mean : does it work for all computers, also those without Intel CPU ? etc. ?

Comment: The library supports Intel and compatible processors and is available for Windows, Linux and OS X operating systems. it does not support ARM processors .

Comment: I was asking myself this very thing just today!